# Using Elevation and Ripple in ImageButton

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-elevation

I'm trying to set elevation and ripple effect at the same time on a ImageButton.
I'm running LOLLIPOP.

Here is the code:

```xml
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
```

My theme is: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

With this code i'm only getting the ripple.
If i remove the background (ripple), i get elevation.

**EDITED:**

Note: All screenshots were taken with the image being clicked (a long press).

I've tested with the `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` and i got a ripple and the background is a square, but no elevation:

[image]

with the `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` i got a ripple with circular background, but no elevation:

[image]

without the background attribute i got the elevation, and the default `ImageButton` background:

[image]

What i need is a **circular ripple background and elevation at the same time**.

Comment: You're using a borderless background. A borderless element will not have a shadow. That's why.

Comment: what theme you are using?

Comment: I've updated the question with that information.

Comment: was this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been five years now but I revisited this and a solution is to use `foreground` instead of `background`:

```xml
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like shadows, borderless ripples are projected onto the nearest parent surface -- which means they cannot cast shadows. Consider using a bordered ripple instead:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, please, give a look at the edited question.